# Target "nodeps" does not exist in the project "android_gingerbread"

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow along with the tutorial at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android to allow an android app to control a robot running ROS. I am getting an error requesting "nodeps" in android_gingerbread.

Can anyone tell me what this means and/or how I can fix the error?

The error follows:

```
  BUILD FAILED
  /home/steve/ROS_DIR/appmanandroid/build_app.xml:116: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/steve/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:485: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  Target "nodeps" does not exist in the project "android_gingerbread". 
  
  Total time: 2 seconds
  Executing command: ['ant']
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package android_app_chooser written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/steve/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120117-203007/android_app_chooser/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< android_app_chooser [FAIL] [ 93.17 seconds ]           
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package android_app_chooser. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 63 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/steve/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120117-203007
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12675/target-%22nodeps%22-does-not-exist-in-the-project-%22android_gingerbread%22./) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-18**:
download patch from http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=76 then run [roscd rosjava_core] and [patch -p1 < ./rosjava_core.patch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=76 and apply the patch there to rosjava_core.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-18**:
found answer here. http://hansengel.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/patch-files-in-unix-linux/

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-18**:
ok great. thank you for your help. I have downloaded it and placed it into the rosjava_core directory. How do I "apply" the patch?